# Click a Paragraph in Time or Hide it

Tags: jquery

I have a paragraph on a page. If the user clicks on it, it hides. If no click is made in 6 seconds, it hides itself.

```
$("#parahide").on("click", function () {
    $(this).slideUp('400');
});
```

How do I code the para to hide itself in 6 seconds? Something with setTimeOut or any other way?

Comment: Something with `.setTimeout()`, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
var myTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
    $("#parahide").slideUp('400');
}, 6000);

$("#parahide").on("click", function () {
    $(this).slideUp('400');
    clearTimeout(myTimeout);
});
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/ghorg12110/5dg8rf0k/1/

Comment: How I use ClearTimeout here. Also why is it used?

Comment: @user1089173 `ClearTimeout` is useless here. `ClearTimeout` prevent the function set with the `setTimeout()` to execute. `setTimeout()` is executed only once.

Comment: Magnus has shown a clearTimeout example. You mean that is wrong?

Comment: @user1089173 The `setTimeout()` method calls a function or evaluates an expression after a specified number of milliseconds. The `setInterval()` method will continue calling the function until `clearInterval()` is called. You need to hide your `p` just once, so use `setTimeout()`.

Comment: Great. Understood but as Magnus says "You should also clearTimeout to avoid slideUp being triggered if it's already clicked." Isn't that a valid usecase for using clearTimeout here..

Comment: I don't think `clearTimeout` is needed in this situation.  If `#parahide` has already been "slid up," the second call to `slideUp` will simply be ignored.

Comment: I did a test by adding a console.log and the clearTimeout was indeed needed. If I click the para, the console was printed that means the setTimeout function executed. However I called clearTimeout in the click, the console never got printed. That means it is needed so that an the timeout function does not fire right?

Comment: @user1089173 updated my answer with a `clearTimeout`

Comment: "ignored" was a poor choice of wording.  I meant the second call to `slideUp` wouldn't actually slide the paragraph up again.  So I don't think `clearTimeout` is needed.

Comment: But if additional code were added to the `setTimeout` function, you *may* need to clear the timer.  So it's not a bad idea to use `clearTimeout`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of jQuery's `delay` and `dequeue`:

```js
$("#parahide").on("click", function () {
  $(this).dequeue().slideUp('400');
}).delay(6000).slideUp('400');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="parahide">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
```

Note that `dequeue` is needed – otherwise the animation keeps waiting until `delay` is finished.

Comment: Thanks. How is this approach better than setTimeout?

Comment: It's not necessarily better – it's simply an alternative, which  may be more succinct.

Comment: Actually I am trying to understand this conceptually. That's why can you elaborate what do you mean by more succint and how would you set up a setTimeout example and compare it with yours.

Comment: Others have posted good `setTimeout` examples, so I simply wanted to show an alternative.  By "succinct", I meant it may be shorter, because you don't need to create or clear a separate timer.

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
$('#parahide').click(function(){ //hides element when click is made
   $(this).slideUp('400'); 
});

var fun = setTimeout(function () {
    $("#parahide").slideUp('400');
},6000); //will hide element in 6 seconds if no click is made

fun();
clearTimeout(fun);
```

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/2oj6pv1q/1/

Comment: How I use ClearTimeout here. Also why is it used?

Comment: The setInterval() method will continue calling the function until clearInterval() is called, or the window is closed.

Comment: Ok how do I call it here. Can you show in your example. Also why are we using SetInterval instead of SetTimeout here?

Comment: Thanks why did you call fun() explicitly? Also why not use setTimeOut here. What adv does setInterval have over setTimeout?

Comment: We **are** using setTimeout here, we call the function explicitly because functions are objects and we are setting `var fun` to the setTimeout function, then we need to call it, otherwise it will never run :) ...and the only reason we are storing it in a variable is because we need to call `clearInterval()` later.

Comment: +1. I don't know why was this downvoted. Perfectly legitimate and correct answer.

Answer (score -1):

Use This code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<div id= 'successMessage'>Hide this Div</div>  
<script>
    setTimeout(function() {
            $("#successMessage").hide()
        }, 6000);
        $('#successMessage').click(function(){
            $("#successMessage").hide()
    });
</script>
```